# How to upload a PDF file to a folder acessable after application is exported?

Tags: c#, winforms, io, openfiledialog

I'm developing an application with Windows Forms where I need to upload a PDF file from the user's computer using the OpenFileDialog function and I want to put that file into a folder.

I have the following:

```
if (!Directory.Exists("CaracterSheet"))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory("CaracterSheet");
            }
            OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            dialog.Filter = "PDF files | *.pdf";
            dialog.Multiselect = false;
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string path = dialog.FileName;
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open), new UTF8Encoding()))
                {
                   
                }
            }
```

When I click a button, it opens the File Dialog and, after the user chooses a file, it saves that file. However, I do not know and cannot find out how I could save the file into a folder called "CaracterSheet".

I would be very glad if you could help me.

Comment: *'Folder inside the project'* belongs to the development time, when you develop and debug your application in Visual Studio. When you distribute your application, there's no project file, there will be .exe of your application which is basically in a folder. [Application.StartupPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) is the start up folder of your application.

Comment: The files that you have in your project structure, if you copy them to output directory (or distribute them with application as content files), they will be copied in the same folder structure that you have in your project.

Comment: @RezaAghaei So how can I do it so when I export the application, the path comes with it?

Comment: where do you want that folder to be? Is it supposed to be a well known place so users can open it later using a PDF veiwer , or is it somehwere private that your app needs to store it so it can get at it later

Comment: you might find this useful https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=net-6.0

Comment: @pm100 I want somewhere private so my app can access it later and even open the PDF file

Comment: @pm100 The concept of a hidden special folder (if that is what it is) sounds interesting but I'm still clueless on how to use it. I've done some researching and am still confused on how to use it

Comment: I don't mind if the users can access the folder if they go on the app's folder tho, Its not a concern

Answer (score 0):

Use this path

```
 Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

Description of that folder

> The directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific data for the current roaming user. A roaming user works on more than one computer on a network. A roaming user's profile is kept on a server on the network and is loaded onto a system when the user logs on.

if not that one then

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
```

> The directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific data that is used by the current, non-roaming user.

Comment: What is a roaming user? How do I make the distinction between a roaming user and a non-roaming user? And although this is really useful and I thank you for this knowledge, my main question and struggle was with saving the file into a folder. I know it seems basic but I cannot find information that helps me